# php validation removes the data from html input

Tags: php, html, validation

I'm having some problem with html input validation using PHP. The validation itself is working. I have two inputs: name and office. 
If I enter a value on Name input but i didn't put value to the office input and click the submit button, the validation on office input works but it CLEAR/null the data i entered on name input

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my PHP validation:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $signatory_name = $_POST['sig_name'];
    $signtory_position = $_POST['sig_position'];

    if (!$_POST['sig_name']) {
            $errname='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error: Please Enter Your Name</div>';
        }

    if (!$_POST['sig_office']) {
            $erroffice='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error: Please Enter Your office</div>';
        }
}
```

this is my html code

```
<form action="signatory.php" method="Post" role="form">
<input class="form-control " id="signatoryname" name="sig_name" placeholder="Name:" >
<input class="form-control " id="signatoryoffice" name="sig_office" placeholder="Office:">
</form>
```

Comment: It's not clear on how your re-populating your form after validation failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are doing or trying to do but here is my attempt:

First: You should know that `if (!$_POST['sig_name']) {` means if the value assigned is FALSE you may want to reconsider this and use `empty()` instead.

After validating the inputs you need to repopulate the form with the submitted values - here is an example:

```
<?php

    $errname = "";
    $erroffice= "";
    if (!empty($_POST)) {   // Only if there are POST values attached.

        $signatory_name = $_POST['sig_name'];
        $signtory_position = $_POST['sig_position'];

        if (empty($_POST['sig_name'])) {
            $errname='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error: Please Enter youre Name</div>';
        }

        if (empty($_POST['sig_office'])) {
             $erroffice='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error: Please Enter youre office</div>';
        }
        if (empty($errname) && empty($erroffice)) {

             //Do whatever you need with the validated inputs...

        } else {
            //Expose the alerts:
            echo $errname.$erroffice;
        }
    }
?>


<form method="POST" role="form">
    <input class="form-control" id="signatoryname" name="sig_name" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['sig_name']))?$_POST['sig_name']:""; ?>" placeholder="Name:" />
    <input class="form-control" id="signatoryoffice" name="sig_office" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['sig_office']))?$_POST['sig_office']:""; ?>" placeholder="Office:" />

    <!-- rest of your form and buttons -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-populate your form as Scuzzy said.

Most browsers might do you for you, but you can't rely on it.

```
<form action="signatory.php" method="Post" role="form">
<input class="form-control " id="signatoryname" name="sig_name" placeholder="Name:" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['sig_name']) ? $_POST['sig_name'] : ''; ?>">
<input class="form-control " id="signatoryoffice" name="sig_office" placeholder="Office:" value="<?php echo !empty($_POST['sig_office']) ? $_POST['sig_office'] : ''; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Also remove this snippet box its not doing nothing just confusing.

Comment: You won't get an undefined index notice because it's wrapped around a !empty ternary statement. If it's empty then it will output an empty string.